# How i can track if a user come to my page using the browser back button or not?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new with javascript and i have to implement some functionality with javascript. I want to redirect users who are coming to my site via browser back button.
SO how i can track my website visitors that they are coming to my site via browser back button or directly by typing my site URL in a browser tab.
I am able to find out similar solution but all those are working for the exiting web page users but i want to implement this for incoming users so whether they are coming to my web page via browser back button or not.
I will really appreciate if someone will be able to guide me about this.
Thank you!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript or jQuery browser back button click detector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17594413/javascript-or-jquery-browser-back-button-click-detector)

Comment: Thanks for your response but Sorry but this is not a solution to my problem. It is working for the existing users who are already on my page but i want to track incoming users so whether they are coming to my web page via browser back button or not.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Back button redirect script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30990027/back-button-redirect-script)

Comment: I would honestly be surprised if there was a way to detect this.  Seems like a very edge use case.

Comment: So @David is it not possible?

Answer (score 0):

I've tackled this problem using local storage .. simply put

**Example :**

```
window.onload = function(){

    var timesVisited = window.localStorage.getItem('tracker');

    if(!timesVisited){

        //If never visited set tracker for first time

        window.localStorage.setItem('tracker' , JSON.stringify({count : 1}))
        return;

    }else{

        timesVisited = JSON.parse(timesVisited).count
    }

    if(timesVisited > 1){
        alert('Welcome Back !!!!')
    }

}
```

Local value storage is permanent until deleted by you or user

**Hope this helps**

Answer (score 0):

You can inspect and parse `document.referrer` to see if user came from inside your site or elsewhere

Comment: Thanks for your answer and time. I am already using this but it is not giving correct result.

Comment: *" not giving correct result"* doesn't explain much

Comment: Sometime it returns undefined and some time an incorrect page url. I mean it is not returning previous page url what i ll need.