# Change content of previously displayed page when hitting back button

Tags: php

Is there a way to change the webpage to which a user returns by clicking back button only through the use of PHP (no AJAX)?

To illustrate, let's assume this scenario: I have a website programmed in PHP with a home page and a 'contact us' page. The PHP script for the "contact us" page generates the contact form and displays it, and it also processes it by submitting the form to itself. The application flow is like this:

Step 1: Home page (user clicks on "contact us")

Step 2: Contact form page (user fills form and clicks submit)

Step 3: Contact form page (script processes user input and displays success message).

What I would like to do is to direct a user that has reached step 3 back to step 1 if it hits the back button in the browser (i.e. avoid showing again the contact form), but only using PHP, no AJAX or Javascript whatsoever. Is this possible?

Comment: This shouldn't be a big deal. You can store history on your own. You can set cookies, create static files, store into db, php session handling, maybe more....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## The Answer is Yes and No

If one reads your question very accurately you actually ask for two different issues:

> Change content of previously displayed page when hitting back button

*Answer: **Jepp!** Actually thats not a big deal.*

> Is there a way to change the webpage to which a user returns by clicking back button only through the use of PHP (no AJAX)?

*Answer: **Nope!** It always will be the page before the current one in the stack of the browsers history log.* But as mentioned above you can absolutely change the content of this page in subject to the previous page.

*Example:* Lets say one is on site "home.php", navigates to "contact.php" and then hits the back button. He definitely will be back again on site "home.php" (at least with PHP-only). But the PHP script on "home.php" can be aware of which was the previous page and deliver a completely different view. Independent from that the url in the browsers address bar will remain as "home.php", its up to you whatever content will be displayed.

To circumvent this you only could do a redirect to actually change the location.

---

### Lets Start With The Basics

If you want to make decisions based on the previous page you definetely must know which was the previous page the user visited - right?
Of course there isn't only one solution but for the setup you described I recommend to make use of [PHP session](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php). Actually you only need the [session_start() function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) and the [$_SESSION superglobal](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php) and also the [header() function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) if you want to redirect your audience.

#### Maybe you want to have a look at the mockup I made to bootstrap the scenario.

*This is just one file, behaves exactly the way you are asking for ("direct a user that has reached step 3 back to step 1 if it hits the back button in the browser").* **It should work out of the box as it is** - so feel free to test it on a server.

```
<?php

session_start();

// get and sanitize page id
$view = key( $_GET );
if ( !$view || 'home' != $view && 'contact_us' != $view && 'thank_you' != $view ) {
    $view = 'home';
}

// get last page id and set current page as the new last page
$last_view = $_SESSION['last_view'];
$_SESSION['last_view'] = $view;

// VALIDATE VIEW
// redirect or manipulate the assumed page under specific circumstances
if ( 'thank_you' == $last_view ||
     'thank_you' == $view && 'contact_us' != $last_view ) {
    // redirect version
    header('Location: /?home');
    /* change assumed page version (just uncomment the line below
     * and delete the one above to see the different behavior)
     * the delivered content will be the same in this case but the adress bar
     * will not change accordingly
     */
    //$view = 'home';
}

?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title><?php echo $view; ?></title>
</head>
<body>

<nav>
    <?php echo 'home' == $view
        ? '<a href="/?contact_us">Contact Us</a>'
        : '<a href="/?home">Home</a>'; ?>
</nav>

<h1>last page was "<?php echo $last_view; ?>"
    and current one is "<?php echo $view; ?>"</h1>

<?php if ( 'home' == $view ) : ?>
    <!-- content home or content when last page was thank you -->
    <h2>Welcome Home</h2>

<?php elseif ( 'contact_us' == $view ) : ?>
    <!-- content contact_us -->
    <h2>Contact Us</h2>
    <form action="?thank_you" method="POST">
        <input name="name" value="" placeholder="Whats your name?" required>
        <input type="submit">
    </form>

<?php else : ?>
    <!-- content thank_you -->
    <h2>Thank You So Much "<?php echo $_POST['name']; ?>"</h2>

<?php endif;
```

**Here is a version that should be more suiteable to your current setup in subject to how to get a page id**

```
<?php
session_start();

// get your page id by filename in conjuction with $_POST data
// if your form at site "contact_us.php" uses `method="get"` just change "$_POST" to "$_GET"
$view = $_POST ? 'thank_you' : pathinfo( $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], PATHINFO_FILENAME );

$last_view = $_SESSION['last_view'];
$_SESSION['last_view'] = $view;

if ( 'thank_you' == $last_view ||
     'thank_you' == $view && 'contact_us' != $last_view ) {
    header('Location: /'); // will redirect to the root of your domain
    //$view = 'home';
}
?><!DOCTYPE html>
```

## So Everything Fine Now?

*Nope - not at all IMHO!*

There is much more then beeing on a page and hitting the back button. What about the reload button for example. Or what about hitting the back button multiple times very fast or different combinations of the said. If you try to consider every or even just a lot of possible circumstances you will probably get bad headaches I bet! Thats just very hacky - you know :]

**Again:** you can go ahead with my script as a starting point and if its really just about hitting the back button then it will do it for you.

---

But what about a much better solution???

## Recommendation

*Do it in one page and do it with AJAX.* Not in general but in the scenario you had desribed!

**Actually this would be more simple and straight forward!**

---

If you really want to stay with with PHP only then here is a maybe

## Better Approach

When the user submitted the form one can catch the current timestamp, add some extra time (a phase in which "contact us" will redirect to home) and deploy this timestamp as $_SESSION variable.

```
<?php
session_start();

// redirect to home page if in restricted period and not on home page
if ( $_SESSION['restricted_period'] &&
     $_SESSION['restricted_period'] > $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'] ) {
    if ( 'contact_us.php' == pathinfo( $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], PATHINFO_BASENAME ) ) {
    // if ( 'contact_us' == key( $_GET ) ) { // that would be suitable for the mockup above
        header('Location: /'); // will redirect to the root of your domain
    }
} else {
    $_SESSION['restricted_period'] = null;
}

// if your form at site "contact_us.php" uses `method="get"` just change "$_POST" to "$_GET"
if ( $_POST ) { // the "thank you" part
    // means the visitor will not be able to visit "contact us" for 45 seconds from now on
    $_SESSION['restricted_period'] = strtotime('+45 seconds'); // short for testing
    // change to '+10 minutes', '+1 hour', whatever you like
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, +1 for thoroughness.

Comment: You are welcome! BTW (just asking for curiosity): what will be your strategy now? Why you don't want to use ajax?

Comment: Actually, it was to confirm that I followed the right path. I'm intermediate to advanced in PHP, but absolutely ignorant in ajax (at least until a few days ago). I believed I needed to learn how to use it if I wanted to resolve the functionality mentioned in my question, so I went through the trouble, but I wanted to confirm that there was no other **sensible** way. So thank you for your response, it made me see that indeed ajax is the sensible option!

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use header() directive in your PHP file. Unfortunately this will not work with browser button. This code will look like these:

Your form when submitted direct to script.php file.

```
<form action="script.php" method="post">
     //form controls
</form>
```

script.php file.

```
<?php
   //Do your stuff with data from user
   header("Location: index.php"); //this send to first page
?>
```

Additionally you can send to first page some GET parameters to change content or do something else like:

```
<?php
   //Do your stuff with data from user
   header("Location: index.php?action=dosomething");
?>
```

You have to remember that header must be first data that is outputed from script.php file.

I hope my answer helped.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to control browser events like back or forward button in PHP, because PHP is processed at the server side not at the client side. So you can't do this in PHP.
But you can use HISTORY APIs in JavaScript to make user redirect to the step 1. 
You may get more help here
[Back button redirect script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30990027/back-button-redirect-script)

PS:Changing the browser behaviour is generally a no no.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You cant, but you can use a trick, you can create a session var on step 3 then when the user use the back buttom yes or yes will go to step 2 but u can make a condition is var session exist go to step 1  making a redirect