# Javascript behavior between 2 different functions that I don't understand

Tags: javascript

I'm a Java developer not well-versed in front-end technologies, so I hope this question isn't too dumb. I have 2 scripts inline on an html page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function printReceipt(orderId,email) {
            var printWindowSettings;
            var browserUserAgent = navigator.userAgent;

            if (browserUserAgent.indexOf("Chrome") > -1) {
                printWindowSettings = "status=0,toolbar=0,menubar=0,height=500,width=1000,scrollbars=1";
            } else {
                printWindowSettings = "status=0,toolbar=0,location=0,menubar=0,height=500,width=1000,scrollbars=1,noopener=1";
            }

            var path = "/shop/printReceipt?orderid="+orderId;
            if (email!=null)
                path+="&email=" + email; 
            var docPrint = window.open(path, '_blank', printWindowSettings);
            if (docPrint == null) console.log("window open returned null");
        }
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        bajb_backdetect.OnBack = function()
        {
            window.history.back=function(){
              console.log("Back Button Pressed.")
              document.location='/shop/shoppingCart.seam';
            }
        }
    </script>
```

`printReceipt()` is invoked in the `onClick()` handler of an anchor tag.

```
<div class="pull-left" style="padding-bottom:20px;"><a href="#" onclick="javascript:printReceipt(apaOrder.orderId);" class="btn btn-primary-custom"><i class="fa fa-print" aria-hidden="true" style="padding-right:6px;"></i>Print Receipt</a></div>
```

What I'm finding is that when `printReceipt()` is invoked, the following script (to manage the back button) gets invoked also. So when `printReceipt()` is called, my browser navigates to `/shop/shoppingCart.seam`.

Why would this be? How do I get around this?

Comment: how is `printReceipt` invoked? You've not shown that

Comment: I've updated my question, thanks.

Comment: Try setting the event listener for the "back button" to `null`.

Comment: Can you show me what that looks like? I really don't know what you're saying, sorry.

Comment: Which button are you talking about? You are saying that you know what function is being called when you click on the anchor tag, can you provide a context of that?

Comment: I thought I did. I updated my answer to show that the onClick of the anchor tag invokes printReceipt.

Comment: The issue with this is that you don't know which other function is being executed, but you know it is since you are being redirected to an unexpected URL, right?

Comment: Almost. printReceipt does execute, and then immediately after, the bajb_backdetect.OnBack gets executed. Perhaps I don't understand js anonymous functions, but I don't understand why the second script executes.

Comment: Is your `bajb_backdetect.OnBack = function()
        {
            window.history.back=function(){
              console.log("Back Button Pressed.")
              document.location='/shop/shoppingCart.seam';
            }
        }` neccesary? What is your expected function from that script? If you didn't wrote it, better remove it. And see what happens with your app.

Comment: That script is part of a 3rd party utility to direct the page to the shopping cart if the user hits the back button. Yes, it's necessary, but i'm open to any ideas as to how to improve it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a bit of research about your issue, and since you mention that you are using a third party script (which is not always the best for a developer), I found something that may help you get rid of it.

This method will need you to delete the third party script you already have (or comment it). Since we are going to handle the back button in a different way.

In the **script tag** where you had the following code:

```
bajb_backdetect.OnBack = function() {
    window.history.back = function() {
        console.log("Back Button Pressed.")
        document.location = '/shop/shoppingCart.seam';
    }
}
```

Replace it with this code:

```
(function(window, location) {
history.replaceState(null, document.title, location.pathname+"#!/history");
history.pushState(null, document.title, location.pathname);

window.addEventListener("popstate", function() {
  if(location.hash === "#!/history") {
    history.replaceState(null, document.title, location.pathname);
    setTimeout(function(){
      location.replace("/shop/shoppingCart.seam"); //Here goes your URL 
    },0);
  }
}, false);
}(window, location));
```

And now, if you did remove the third party script (or commented it), you should be able to see the expected behavior.

If you want to see more about this, there is a question similar to this that has been already answered saying the best approach for handling the window back event is doing it by yourself.

I took this information from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30999534/5568741), just complemented it with the explanation and code for your specific issue. Hope it helps.

***Note:*** If it still not working, you will need to provide a more open context of your code, since there might be something else causing it to not work.

Comment: Thank you! But which part of my code am I replacing? Do I keep the `bajb_backdetect.OnBack = `?

Comment: Nope, remove the entire JavaScript code in that script tag and place the code above.

Comment: It works! It works!! I can't thank you enough for your patience with me.

Comment: @user1660256 An upvote and accepting the answer if I really helped you is enough my friend, it helps me more than what you think!:)

Answer (score 1):

Probably the anchor being clicked causes the browser to follow the link.

Given this:

```html
<a href="" onclick="printReceipt(10, 'person@site.com')">click me</a>
```

Clicking that link will run the function and then the page will reload. Your back detection script will notice that the page is being unloaded and do stuff (apparently).

Change it to:

```html
<a href="" onclick="printReceipt(10, 'person@site.com'); return false">click me</a>
```

To prevent the link from being followed.

Comment: I see in your edit that your href is a `#`, which should prevent your browser from leaving the page. Try to add the `return false` to the onlick anyways and see if it helps. Otherwise I think we need more context to figure this out.

Comment: no equals sign, just `return false`. It would also have worked I believe, with your 3rd party script intact. It will prevent your state from being ruined when the link is clicked.

Comment: Hmm, i think that was a typo. I didn't put the equals sign in my code.